# Property for CharacterEncodingFilter in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wonder if can replace the filter CharacterEncodingFilter by the HttpEncodingProperties.

I saw at documentation below ones:

```
# HTTP encoding (HttpEncodingProperties)
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

Will it have the same effect that applying the filter manually?
Another question, if I want to inform Spring Boot to keep the filter (properties) as async. Via filter I can inform it, setAsyncSupported(true).

Tks,

Comment: To answer the first part of your question - yes it is the same. If you look for usages of `HttpEncodingProperties`, you will find `HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration` class where the filter is created by Spring Boot based on those properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot has many **auto configurations** per default, and http encoding is just one more using this concept.

Looking into the source code of ***HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration*** class, the filter ***CharacterEncodingFilter*** is created to encode all requests made to server. If you don't specify any property in *application.properties* the filter will be created using UTF-8, however if you decide creating this filter manually Spring Boot will use yours.

*See source code:*
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.6.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration.java